# Auto logging / tracking records changes at MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, logging

how can I set automatic recording all changes that were done at tables records (Updates) and to get some info / logging summery?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different options available to do this, and also depend on which version of SQL Server you're running. Here they are in order of least complicated to implement and most standard, in my opinion:

1. [**Temporal Tables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) - These generate a *log* table for each table you want to track changes on, with who, when, and what the change was.
2. [**Change Data Capture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Similar to **Temporal Tables**, but on a more global level. System tables of the same database are used to log the changes of your tables within that database.
3. [**Database DML Triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - You can create an `AFTER TRIGGER` that manually logs the changes into a separate table. This is more of a homebrew solution and a little more work than using either of the first two features.
4. [**Audit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - This globally tracks multiple events, a subset of which would be DML changes such as `UPDATES` and `INSERTS`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks! I meant to go back and double check that part as I felt I was misremembering. Just updated my answer to fix it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way would be to use SQL Server Auditing but there are alternative options too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15